# Initialized function not being called on any panel Sencha extjs

Tags: extjs

Here is an example of the code I'm using, I'm creating my own component from a panel and loading with the require property

```
Ext.define("VMPWorld.view.Navbar.MainNavbar", {
xtype: 'MainNavbar',
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
requires: [
    'VMPWorld.view.Navbar.NavbarContainer'
],
config: {
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },

    ui: 'none',

    items: [{
        xtype: 'NavbarContainer',
        height: 700
    }]
},

initialize: function() {
    this.callParent();
    console.log("Called");
}
```

});

Comment: `define` means declare a class. Where do you create an instance?

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen such template function. If you want to call it automatically, consider **initComponent** or handler of some event such as **render**. Anyway, you should provide some additional information on how you expect the function to be called.